# Spring Boot JSP page works but XmlViewResolver not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, itext

I am developing a spring boot application, I am trying to use XmlViewResolver to view the pdf from predefined template using itext. Successfully getting the jsp page when I access the "/welcome" and "/invoice", but failed when I try "/pdf".
Please let me know what's wrong. Why the pdf bean is not working as expected?

> **Whitelabel Error Page**
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>
> /WEB-INF/jsp/pdf.jsp

Below are the codes

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String hello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg", "XmlViewResolver Demo");
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping("/invoice")
public String getInvoiceInfo() {
    return "invoice";
}

@RequestMapping("/pdf")
public String getPdfInfo() {
    return "pdf";
}
}
```

JspConfig.java

```
@Component
public class JspConfig {
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    bean.setOrder(2);
    return bean;
}
}
```

XmlConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class XmlConfig {
@Bean
public XmlViewResolver xmlViewResolver() {
    XmlViewResolver resolver = new XmlViewResolver();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("xml/user-view.xml");
    resolver.setLocation(resource);
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
}
```

user-view.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="invoice" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
    <property name="url" value="WEB-INF/template/invoice.jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="pdf" class="com.example.config.PdfView">
    <property name="url" value="WEB-INF/template/invoiceTemplate.pdf" />
</bean>
```

PdfView.java

```
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class PdfView extends AbstractPdfStamperView implements MessageSourceAware {

@Override
protected void mergePdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, PdfStamper   stamper, HttpServletRequest request, response) throws Exception {

    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    String customerName = (String) model.get("customerName");
    stamper.getAcroFields().setField("name", customerName);
    stamper.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Are You sure You that this classpath resource ""xml/user-view.xml"" is actually loaded? You could try to print/use debugger ust after constructor call to ClassPathResource to see value of method resource.exists(). I know that You see that the resource is in your project but using ClassPathResource is sometimes a little bit tricky

Comment: @masian: Thanks for your reply. yes it's loaded. I have updated the xml file and error details "/invoice" shows the page, but failed for "/pdf". Please check the error